# Undo buffer-search in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

After doing a `(re-search-forward str)` in the current buffer, it would be nice in some cases to have an easy method to return to the previous buffer position. The behavior should be like `(undo)` for buffer changes. So if I do two searches forward, first from position A to B, and then from B to C, I would like to press a key to go back one step (from C to B), and pressing the key again would leave me at A..

Comment: Not sure if that would answer your question but since i use regexp search a lot, i bound `C-s` and `C-r` to `isearch-forward-regexp` and `isearch-backward-regexp` then moving back and forth is just a matter of hitting the proper key combos.  Without pressing `RET`, i.e., not quitting the search mode, `C-g` will cancel the search and go back to where the search started.  If i did press `RET` at one of those found patterns, then `C-U SPC` will also take me back to the point where i started the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this

```
(global-set-key
 (kbd "M-p")
 (lambda()(interactive) (set-mark-command 4)))
```

I can jump backwards one by one through a few <kbd>C-M-s</kbd>.

Note that this works for `isearch-forward-regexp`, not for plain
`re-search-forward` (this one doesn't set the mark).
But with elisp it's no problem - just call `push-mark` before
`re-search-forward`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.. What is the purpose of the argument to `set-mark-command`? (That is: the number `4`)

Comment: I don't know why 4. Any numeric value works in the same way. Use 42 if you like.

Comment: Ok:) I just found the `show-marks` mode ( http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/show-marks.el ). Maybe this can be used for my purpose?

Comment: Håkon Hægland, abo-abo: You should note that `4` *is* a special value (not necessarily for this function, but in general). When `C-u` is used (once, with no explicit number), it passes the raw value `(4)` which is just `4` when interpreted as a numeric prefix arg. See `C-h i g` `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments`. It is not uncommon to see `4` or `'(4)` passed in code to trigger the prefix argument behaviour of a function.

Comment: Also, you may find that `C-u C-SPC` (or `C-u C-@`) is sufficient for your needs. That's the same thing as the accepted answer, but using existing bindings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `re-search-forward` in Lisp code (and you probably should be, if you are using it at all, even though it is a command), then *do* ***not*** *set the mark* in order to be able to return to your starting point.

Instead, simply save the starting position (`(point)`) as, say, variable `beg`, and then use `goto-char beg`.

See this paragraph in `(elisp) The Mark`:

```
 Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often try to use the mark for the
 wrong purposes.  The mark saves a location for the user's
 convenience.  An editing command should not alter the mark unless
 altering the mark is part of the user-level functionality of the
 command.  (And, in that case, this effect should be documented.)
 To remember a location for internal use in the Lisp program, store
 it in a Lisp variable.  For example:

      (let ((beg (point)))
        (forward-line 1)
        (delete-region beg (point))).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not think this is what I am looking for.. I am working on a major mode, or an enhancement of a major mode, and so there is an option to search forward to the definition of a "function" referred to at point by pressing a keyboard shortcut. Now later, the user may decide to return to the original point by pressing another keyboard shortcut.. This is what I am trying to achieve..

Comment: In that case, just set the mark.  Users can navigate back to the position normally, using the mark ring.  Or if you want a command that moves directly to that particular location, then save the location in a global variable...

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, the following seems to work:

```
(defun my-search-fun (str)
  (interactive)
  (push-mark)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (re-search-forward str))

(defun my-undo-search ()
  (interactive)
  (pop-mark)
  (goto-char (mark))
```